# Partial (per-file/folder) branching/tagging in Mercurial?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, dvcs, tortoisehg

In the classic VCSs (CVS/SVN) I can add new files/folders in one branch and then "tag" them with some branch tag so they appear on another branch *as well* (from where they may diverge again). This works by updating your working copy to a particular state and then setting the branch tag.

How can I achieve something similar in Mercurial? I searched, far and wide, but there appears to be no way of moving only a few files/folders onto another branch.

In my case some historical branch received some updates that should now be moved onto the currently active branch (that was before the repo was converted from Subversion to Mercurial). Is there any method that retains the history of these files/this folder? Or would I have to re-introduce the current state of these files to the other branch (i.e. start from scratch)?

Side-note: there are several hundred conflicting changes between the tips of both branches. That's why I'm looking for an alternative to full-fledged merging between the branches (which would also be a problem because one of the branches would cease to exist after a merge).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Mercurial transplant extensio](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TransplantExtension)n should do the trick. Transplant re-applies a changeset to a branch of your choice. It's commonly used as a way to move a bug fix from one branch to another (ie: from some long-running branch corresponding to a released version of code to the actively developed default branch).

Transplant is distributed with Mercurial, but you might have to enable it by adding the following lines to  your Mercurial.ini (or .hgrc):

```
[extensions]
transplant=
```

From TortoiseHg you can update to the destination changeset (ie: where you are placing the fixes) and then right-click on the changeset you want to move and select "Transplant to local". Command line help can be found at the link above.

One caveat is that transplant applies to changesets, and it want to apply the *entire* changeset. So, if a changeset contains some changes you want to apply and some you do not, you've got to do a little more work. One way to get around this is to use the [histedit](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HisteditExtension) extension and break such a changeset into two. This can be complex, and is not recommended if your repo is not locally contains (ie: if it's on a server somewhere). A brute-force option would be to transplant a changeset and then simply undo unwanted changes and commit those mods as a second changeset.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm going to try it on a local clone first, just to be sure. I had played with the transplant extension, but it seemed to be for transplantation of change sets from related clones. The change sets in question modified only that particular folder, so that approach should work. Thanks again.

Comment: Just tried it and it works. I hit some merge conflicts nevertheless, but those are much much fewer, so I'm going to sort them out. Thanks for your help.